# NullPointerException in CheckFilter?

Tags: java, filter, nullpointerexception

I'm having difficulties in Filter class because of NPE. I know what it means and I checked null possibilities but didn't work. What is the reason if you can help me please? here is my code..

```
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    RequestDispatcher rd = null;


    if (session != null) {

        Person user = (Person) session.getAttribute("person");
        String personType=user.getType();  **<----- EXCEPTION HERE**
```

Let me tell you this part of my project... I have and web app which relates servlets, jsp's, MysqlDB, Filters, and java classes ofcourse... I want to check all jsp's for security with my Filter which checks logged user's user type is USER, ADMIN or MANAGER. and above my code i checked if any session up or not (session != null) and if not redirect user to login page again... So how can i avoid NPE here? Thanks for replying

This code continious with if user admin or not and manager or not and goes on... First scope is if(session!=null).. So if it is false then filter redirect user to login.jsp. I can post code if u wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is `user` object is `null`.  The cast works even if the `session.getAttribute("person")` returns `null`

you need to have `null` check on `user`

```
Person user = (Person) session.getAttribute("person");
if(user != null) {
    String personType=user.getType(); 
}
```

Comment: Adding to this: possible reasons could be that you're trying to retrieve a wrong session variable or your session has timed out. You might want to check those things

Comment: My NPE problem is solved.. But i can't access my login page and i dont understand why? Before my NPE problem it works just fine... Any suggestions ?

Comment: Just blank page appears.

Comment: So I clean TomCAT directory and it appears. Thank you.